# How can I set a RSA private key to known string value

Tags: javascript, go, encryption, rsa

I'm working on a solution to encrypt a data value in js with a known rsa public key and then decrypt it with a known rsa private key. I'm using [this website](http://travistidwell.com/blog/2013/09/06/an-online-rsa-public-and-private-key-generator/) to generate public and private rsa keys.

in my js I have something along the lines of

```
    let publicKey = "randomstringofcharacterswfiwe efi wef we ";

    // we create a new JSEncrypt object for rsa encryption
    var rsaEncrypt = new JSEncrypt();
  
    // we set the public key (which we passed into the function)
    rsaEncrypt.setPublicKey(publicKey);

    let encryptedPass = RSAEncrypt.encrypt(val)

    data.set("datavalue", encryptedPass)
```

I have the RSA keys generated online and Im directly addressing them on the front and backend. In the Go I'm trying to decrypt the datavalue with a private key but I don't know how to set the private from the string value I have.

Ideally it'd look something along the lines of

```
func DecryptValue(data *multipart.Form) {

        privateKey = "randomstringofchargeneratedforpublickey"
        RSA_OAEP_Decrypt(strconv.Atoi(data.Value["key"][0]), *privateKey)
    }
```

but in the RSA_OAEP_Decrypt function it has to be a rsa PrivateKey object and I don't know how to convert the string into one in Go.

Comment: JSEncrypt uses PKCS#1 v1.5 padding, no OAEPadding.

Comment: The private key of the linked website has the PKCS#1 format and can be parsed e.g. DER encoded with [`ParsePKCS1PrivateKey()`](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/x509#ParsePKCS1PrivateKey).

Comment: (Which means you should first base 64 decode the text between the header and footer, **then** call the function). Unless somebody wrote a PEM reader / parser of course that you can use.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, Go comes with a PEM encoder in the standard library: https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/pem

Comment: Ah, nice PEM API, that should definitely simplify matters, just get the binary data from the PEM, after checking the `Type` preferably.